# Looping through a list of tuples and removing them

Tags: python, loops, tuples

Im having some difficulty understanding why my loop is not deleting invalid dates from a list of date tuples in the format of dd/mm/yyyy . heres what i have so far :

```
dates = [('12','10','1987'),('13','09','2010'), ('34','02','2002'), ('02','15','2005'),('37','10','2016'),('39','11','2001')]
print(dates)

for date in dates :
    day = int(date[0])
    month = int(date[1])
    year = int(date[2])

    if day > 31 :
        dates.remove(date)


    if month > 12 :
        dates.remove(date)



print(dates)
```

and heres the result :

```
[('12', '10', '1987'), ('13', '09', '2010'), ('34', '02', '2002'), ('02', '15', '2005'), ('37', '10', '2016'), ('39', '11', '2001')]

[('12', '10', '1987'), ('13', '09', '2010'), ('02', '15', '2005'), ('39', '11', '2001')]
```

I'm a total beginner and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never modify the (length of the) list you are looping over. Instead, use for example a temporary list:

```py
dates = [('12','10','1987'),('13','09','2010'), ('34','02','2002'), ('02','15','2005'),('37','10','2016'),('39','11','2001')]
print(dates)

out = []
for date in dates :
    day = int(date[0])
    month = int(date[1])
    year = int(date[2])

    if day > 31 or month > 12:
        continue
    out.append(date)

dates = out

print(dates)
```

The `continue` statement jumps back to the first line of the loop, so the unwanted dates will be skipped.

#### Better alternative conserning dates

Commenting on the "date checking" functionality of the program: It might be really hard to determine by your own rules what dates are acceptable and what are not. Consider for example the Feb 29th, which is only valid on every fourth year.

What you could do instead is to use the `datetime` library to try to parse the strings to datetime objects, and if the parsing fails, you know the date is illegal.

```py
import datetime as dt 

dates = [('12','10','1987'),('13','09','2010'), ('34','02','2002'), ('02','15','2005'),('37','10','2016'),('39','11','2001')]

def filter_bad_dates(dates):
    out = []
    for date in dates:

        try:
            dt.datetime.strptime('-'.join(date), '%d-%m-%Y')
        except ValueError:
            continue

        out.append(date)

    return out


dates = filter_bad_dates(dates)
print(dates)
```

This `try - except` pattern is also called "Duck Typing":

> If it looks like a date and gets parsed like a proper date, then it is probably a proper date.

Comment: So I should create a new list for the correct dates instead of editing an existing list while looping through it. So what was happening in my code? When I deleted a tuple was that making it miss iterations? 

Thanks again.

Comment: You are correct. One way to tackle this is to create empty list and start filling it up instead of modifying thw originals. Yes, that's what happened: you removed something from the list while iterating over it, which caused it to not even check some of the dates. You can see the behaviour of your original code also by printing the dates at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish that with this list comprehension:

```
dates = [('12','10','1987'),('13','09','2010'), ('34','02','2002'), ('02','15','2005'),('37','10','2016'),('39','11','2001')]
dates = [date for date in dates if int(date[1]) < 12 and int(date[0]) < 31]
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
[('12', '10', '1987'), ('13', '09', '2010')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @AnnZen's comprehension approach (+1) though my tendency would be to go more symbolic at the waste of some time and space:

```
dates = [ \
    ('12', '10', '1987'), \
    ('13', '09', '2010'), \
    ('34', '02', '2002'), \
    ('02', '15', '2005'), \
    ('37', '10', '2016'), \
    ('39', '11', '2001'), \
]

dates = [date for (day, month, _), date in zip(dates, dates) if day < '31' and month < '12']

print(dates)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[('12', '10', '1987'), ('13', '09', '2010')]
>
```

As far as @np8's "Never modify the list you are looping over.", that's excellent advice.  Though, again, I might waste some space making the copy upfront to make my code simpler:

```
for date in list(dates):  # iterate over a copy
    day, month, _ = date

    if int(day) > 31 or int(month) > 12:
        dates.remove(date)
```

Though in the end, @np8's filtering through `datetime` seems the most reliable solution.  (+1)

Comment: Why the backslashes?

Comment: @AnnZen, backslashes are the line continuation character in Python. To not use them is a "bad continuation" error according to the PEP-8 syntax checker I use.  I don't like them, particularly because you can't follow them with comments, but occasionally I include them to remind myself how funky this language is.

Comment: *To not use them is a "bad continuation" error* when you say that, do you only mean when we list in a single line, or also when we list in multiple lines, without backslashes?

Comment: @AnnZen, the latter, multiple lines.  Of course, putting the list in a single line goes against PEP-8's unreasonably short 79 character line length limit style recommendation.  Thus the need to break into multiple lines and use continuation characters.

Comment: Note that you don't need continuation backslashes inside parentheses/brackets, you could safely remove the ones in your answer. A 'trick' you can sometimes encounter is using parentheses in combination with implicit string concatenation: `s = ("Start of sentence " <newline> "end")`

Comment: Gee, I never realized we can concat strings like that!